# New records add using kendo Hierachy grid + MVC +Kendo ui

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using hierarchy kendo grid for adding relational record. I am able to add the parent and child record. but i passing below issues.

1. I add the first parent and child record successfully, but i try to second parent record then clear all first parent child records.
2. I am try to read the data source of the grid, but always get parent records only , I am not able to get child records.

I attached clear screen shot image for reference and here provide my test code.

```
<button id="btn" onclick="save()">TEST</button>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = []
            index = data.length + 1;
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                            destroy: function (o) {
                             o.success();
                        },
                        create: function (o) {
                              var record = o.data;
                            record.CheckListId = index;
                            index++;
                            o.success(record);
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            id: "CheckListId",
                            fields: {
                                CheckListId: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                Name: { type: "string" },
                                Description: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                editable: "popup",
                toolbar: ["create"],
                columns: [
                 "Name", "Description",
                { command: ["destroy"] }
                ],
                detailInit: detailInit,
                dataBound: function () {
                    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
                }
            });
            function detailInit(e) {
                $('</div>').appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {

                            destroy: function (o) {
                                //console.log("child destroy");
                                o.success();
                            },
                            create: function (o) {
                                   var record = o.data;
                               record.CheckId = index;
                                index++;
                                record.CheckListId = e.data.CheckListId;
                                o.success(record);
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "CheckId",
                                fields: {
                                    CheckId: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                    CheckListId: { type: "number", editable: false },
                                    Name: { type: "string" },
                                    Description: { type: "string" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    navigatable: true,
                    editable: "popup",
                    toolbar: ["create"],
                    columns: [
                    "Name", "Description",
                    { command: ["destroy"] }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
        function save() {

            var checklist = $("#checklistGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CreateTemplate", "Meeting", Request.RequestContext.Rout`enter code here`eData.Values)',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: kendo.stringify({

                    getCheckList: checklist.toJSON()

                }),
                success: function (data) {![enter image description here][1]
                    //
                },
                error: function (xhr, statusText, err) {
                    alert("Error : Template not created");
                }
            });

        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi anyone please provide answer above question, very urgent,

Comment: Please provide answer any one